# How to zoom between two Google map markers in flutter

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm using the google_maps_flutter package and I'm trying to figure a way to zoom the camera between two placed markers with known positions. Any pointers or sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To zoom between two Lat Lng bounds in google map, you can do as below:

First of all import below library in pubspec.yaml otherwise with the older version, you might not be able to see "getVisibleRegion()" method with google
map controller.

google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.12

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    _controller.complete(controller);

    LatLng latLng_1 = LatLng(40.416775, -3.70379);
    LatLng latLng_2 = LatLng(41.385064, 2.173403);
    LatLngBounds bound = LatLngBounds(southwest: latLng_1, northeast: latLng_2);

    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      addMarker(latLng_1, "Madrid", "5 Star Rating");
      addMarker(latLng_2, "Barcelona", "7 Star Rating");
    });

    CameraUpdate u2 = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bound, 50);
    this.mapController.animateCamera(u2).then((void v){
      check(u2,this.mapController);
    });

  }

  void addMarker(LatLng mLatLng, String mTitle, String mDescription){
    _markers.add(Marker(
      // This marker id can be anything that uniquely identifies each marker.
      markerId: MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString()),
      position: mLatLng,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: mTitle,
        snippet: mDescription,
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    ));
  }

  void check(CameraUpdate u, GoogleMapController c) async {
    c.animateCamera(u);
    mapController.animateCamera(u);
    LatLngBounds l1=await c.getVisibleRegion();
    LatLngBounds l2=await c.getVisibleRegion();
    print(l1.toString());
    print(l2.toString());
    if(l1.southwest.latitude==-90 ||l2.southwest.latitude==-90)
      check(u, c);
  }


  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          markers: _markers,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
          onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is divine. i will check this out and get back to you. once implemented. Thanks a bunch

Comment: What is the role of _center in this? Is this dynamic?

Comment: another solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36653

Comment: //Animating the Camera directly would possibly cause a map size error, so you should delay this instruction by few milliseconds.
`Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      this.mapController.animateCamera(u2).then((void v) {
        check(u2, this.mapController);
      });
    });`

Comment: what is the difference between l1 and l2? They are both getting same visible region

Answer (score 13):

The proposed solution above is good, but LatLngBounds has one important limitation:

```
LatLngBounds({@required this.southwest, @required this.northeast})
  : assert(southwest != null),
    assert(northeast != null),
    assert(southwest.latitude <= northeast.latitude); // <--
```

This means that the first coordinate must be lower and to the left of the second coordinate.

I had to modify the method for different coordinates.

```
    void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    _controller.complete(controller);

    //offerLatLng and currentLatLng are custom

    final LatLng offerLatLng = LatLng(
    double.parse(widget.coordinates.first.latLongList.first.latitude),
    double.parse(widget.coordinates.first.latLongList.first.longitude));

    LatLngBounds bound;
    if (offerLatLng.latitude > currentLatLng.latitude &&
        offerLatLng.longitude > currentLatLng.longitude) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(southwest: currentLatLng, northeast: offerLatLng);
    } else if (offerLatLng.longitude > currentLatLng.longitude) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
          southwest: LatLng(offerLatLng.latitude, currentLatLng.longitude),
          northeast: LatLng(currentLatLng.latitude, offerLatLng.longitude));
    } else if (offerLatLng.latitude > currentLatLng.latitude) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
          southwest: LatLng(currentLatLng.latitude, offerLatLng.longitude),
          northeast: LatLng(offerLatLng.latitude, currentLatLng.longitude));
    } else {
      bound = LatLngBounds(southwest: offerLatLng, northeast: currentLatLng);
    }

    CameraUpdate u2 = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bound, 50);
    this.mapController.animateCamera(u2).then((void v){
      check(u2,this.mapController);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for a really big timesaving snippet :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, super nice work! Thanks!

Comment: Smashed it bro!

Comment: This is better than selected answer . Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Above suggestions are very good.
If you are working with dynamic source/destination this code might work for you:

```
Future<void> updateCameraLocation(
  LatLng source,
  LatLng destination,
  GoogleMapController mapController,
) async {
  if (mapController == null) return;

  LatLngBounds bounds;

  if (source.latitude > destination.latitude &&
      source.longitude > destination.longitude) {
    bounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: destination, northeast: source);
  } else if (source.longitude > destination.longitude) {
    bounds = LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(source.latitude, destination.longitude),
        northeast: LatLng(destination.latitude, source.longitude));
  } else if (source.latitude > destination.latitude) {
    bounds = LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(destination.latitude, source.longitude),
        northeast: LatLng(source.latitude, destination.longitude));
  } else {
    bounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: source, northeast: destination);
  }

  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 70);

  return checkCameraLocation(cameraUpdate, mapController);
}

Future<void> checkCameraLocation(
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate, GoogleMapController mapController) async {
  mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  LatLngBounds l1 = await mapController.getVisibleRegion();
  LatLngBounds l2 = await mapController.getVisibleRegion();

  if (l1.southwest.latitude == -90 || l2.southwest.latitude == -90) {
    return checkCameraLocation(cameraUpdate, mapController);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
await updateCameraLocation(source, destination, controller);
```

Comment: what is the difference between l1 and l2? They are both getting same visible region.